# .NET Blazor - two way data binding with handler method in child component

Tags: .net, blazor

This is my `Blazor` component (in `.Net 8`):

```
@* Components\Pages\Home.razor *@
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h4>Home component</h4>
<input type="number" @bind:get="age" @bind:set="SetAge" />
<h2>Age: @age</h2>

@code {
  int age = 18;

  void SetAge(int value)
  {
    if (value > 0 && value < 110)
      age = value;
  }
}
```

[image]

I try to move all the logic to `About` component and then call it into `Home`:

```
@* Components\Pages\Home.razor *@
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h4>Home component</h4>
<About Age="age" @oninput="@SetAge" />

@code {
  int age = 5;

  void SetAge(int value)
  {
    if (value > 0 && value < 110)
      age = value;
  }
}

@* Components\Pages\About.razor *@
<h4>About component</h4>

<input type="number" @bind:get="Age" @bind:set="SetAge" />
<h2>Age: @Age</h2>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public int Age { get; set; } = 18;

  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback<string> InputChanged { get; set; }
}
```

but my solution is buggy, do not know how to modify components. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified `MrC aka Shaun Curtis`'s answer and this is the final working solution:

```
@* Components\Pages\Home.razor *@
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h4>Home component</h4>
<About @bind-Age="age"  />

@code {
  private int age = 5;
}

@* Components\Pages\About.razor *@
<h4>About component</h4>

<input type="number" @bind:get="Age" @bind:set="OnAgeChanged" />
<h2>Age: @Age</h2>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public int Age { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback<int> AgeChanged { get; set; }

  private async Task OnAgeChanged(int value)
  {
    if (value > 0 && value < 110)
      Age = value;

    await AgeChanged.InvokeAsync(Age);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually notifying the parent of any change.

Check out this link for some more info on two-way binding:
https://blazor-university.com/components/two-way-binding/

```
    @* Components\Pages\About.razor *@
<h4>About component</h4>

<input type="number" @bind:get="Age" @bind:set="((age) => AgeChanged.InvokeAsync(age))" />
<h2>Age: @Age</h2>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public int Age { get; set; } = 18;

  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback<int> AgeChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please give me 'Home' component example too

Comment: In the Home component, just change @oninput="@SetAge" to AgeChanged=SetAge. The only reason you need to even set AgeChanged=SetAge is because you are checking verifying the age. By properly setting the @bind:set in the About component, you've already achieved two-way binding with the Age property in the Home component.

Answer (score 2):

First About.  You need to set up the binding correctly as shown:

```cs
<h4>About component</h4>

<input type="number" @bind:get="Age" @bind:set="this.OnAgeChanged" />
<h2>Age: @Age</h2>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Age { get; set; } = 18;

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> AgeChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnAgeChanged(int value)
    {
        await AgeChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

And then Home.  As your binding parameters are `Age`, you use `@bind-Age` rather than `@bind-Value`

```cs
@page "/"

<h4>Home component</h4>
<About @bind-Age ="this.age" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
    <pre>Age: @age</pre>
</div>

@code {
    int age = 5;
}
```

It's all explained in this MS Documents article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0

### Updated Answer:

In this demo I'm using Blazored.FluentValidation for validaation - https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation.

First install the Nuget package.

Now the model and validator.

```cs
public class Model
{
    public int Age { get; set; } = 5;
}

public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public ModelValidator()
    {
        this.RuleFor(p => p.Age)
            .GreaterThan(5)
            .LessThan(115);
    }
}
```

And About. This detects the presence of an `EditContext` and if one exists calls `Validate` on it when you update the value.

```cs
<h4>About component</h4>

<input type="number" @bind:get="Age" @bind:set="this.OnAgeChanged" />
<h2>Age: @Age</h2>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Age { get; set; } = 18;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> AgeChanged { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext? EditContext { get; set; } 

    private ValidationMessageStore? _validationMessageStore;

    private async Task OnAgeChanged(int value)
    {
        await AgeChanged.InvokeAsync(value);

        if (this.EditContext is not null)
            this.EditContext.Validate();

    }
}
```

And Home which shows how to implement a `EditForm` and basic validation wothour an edit form.

```
@page "/"

<h4>Home component</h4>

<div class="bg-light m-2 p-2">
    <EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="OnSubmitForm">
        <FluentValidationValidator />
        <About @bind-Age="_model.Age" />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

<div class="bg-light m-2 p-2">
    <About @bind-Age="_model1.Age" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnSubmit">Submit</button>
    @if (_validationResult != null && !_validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        @foreach (var message in _validationResult.Errors)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger m-2">
                @message.ErrorMessage
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
    <pre>Age: @_model.Age</pre>
    <pre>Age: @_model1.Age</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private Model _model = new();
    private Model _model1 = new() { Age = 0 };
    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult? _validationResult;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _editContext = new(_model);
        // Fake a database call to populate model
        await Task.Delay(100);
        _model = new();
        _editContext = new(_model);
    }

    private Task OnSubmitForm()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task OnSubmit()
    {
        var validate = new ModelValidator();
        _validationResult = validate.Validate(_model1);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: does not works limitation of `Age`: [0-110]. where to write this logic? please update your anwer

Comment: Are you operating with an `EditForm`?    You can add it to `OnAgeChanged`.

Comment: I'm just learning. please give both solutions: with `Edit Form` and without it and you will be blessed :)

Comment: man, what are you doing here? why this validation?! I just asked simple question and already answered it (modified your answer). Why you overcomplicated simple question? why did you closed my other question as duplication?! camon :(

Comment: You did ask above for different solutions.  And I believe the other question was a duplicate. I did undelete it, but you appear to have deleted it.