# .NET Blazor - two way data binding with handler method in parent component

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I try to implement two way data binding in `Blazor` (`.Net 8`). According to documentation,new way of implementing it is [@bind:get/@bind:set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-bindgetbindset-modifiers-and-avoid-event-handlers-for-two-way-data-binding). This is my solution, it works perfectly:

[image]

```
@* Components\Pages\Home.razor *@
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
 
<h4>Home component</h4>
<About @bind-Age="age"  />
 
@code {
  private int age = 5;
}

@* Components\Pages\About.razor *@
<h4>About component</h4>
 
<input type="number" @bind:get="Age" @bind:set="OnAgeChanged" />
<h2>Age: @Age</h2>
 
@code {
  [Parameter]
  public int Age { get; set; }
 
  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback<int> AgeChanged { get; set; }
 
  private async Task OnAgeChanged(int value)
  {
    if (value > 0 && value < 110)
      Age = value;
 
    await AgeChanged.InvokeAsync(Age);
  }
}
```

now I want to define handler method (`OnAgeChanged()`) in `Home.razor` component (not in `About.razor`) and I did not succeed. this is my buggy solution (I am able to enter for `age` more than 110, restriction [0-110] does not works):

```
@* Components\Pages\Home.razor *@
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h4>Home component</h4>
<About @bind-Age="age" />

@code {
  private int age { get; set; } = 5;

  private async Task OnAgeChanged(int value)
  {
    if (value > 0 && value < 110)
      age = value;
  }
}
    
@* Components\Pages\About.razor *@
<h4>About component</h4>

<input type="number" @bind:get="Age" @bind:set="InvokeParentMethod" />
<h2>Age: @Age</h2>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public int Age { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback<int> AgeChanged { get; set; }

  private async Task InvokeParentMethod(int value)
  {
    await AgeChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
  }
}
```

please help me to solve my problem with `@bind:get/@bind:set` as `Microsoft` advises.

P.S. This is not duplication. [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954644/9904870) question asks about handle method in `child` component and this one asks about handle method in `parent` component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get into `OnAgeChanged` method both parent component and child component

you could try:

```
<About @bind-Age="age" @bind-Age:after="()=>OnAgeChanged(age)"></About>
```

I just followed your codes:

Child Component:

```
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer]
<h4>About component</h4>

<input type="number" @bind:get="Age" @bind:set="OnAgeChanged" />
<h2>Age: @Age</h2>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> AgeChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnAgeChanged(int value)
    {
        if (value > 0 && value < 110)
            Age = value;

        await AgeChanged.InvokeAsync(Age);
    }
}
```

Parent Component:

```
@page "/"
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer]



<About @bind-Age="age" @bind-Age:after="()=>OnAgeChanged(age)"></About>

@code {


    private int age { get; set; }


    
    private async Task OnAgeChanged(int value)
    {
        if (value > 0 && value < 110)
            age = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please give the full version of both components? can't get this to work

Comment: Hi,@DevMis,I've updated,hopes help

Comment: actually it does not works. it always uses `OnAgeChanged()` defined in `About.razor`. say, if I change logic in `Home.razor`'s `OnAgeChanged()` like this: if (value > 0 && value < 50) I still be able to enter more then 50, up to 110.
P.S. I've updated my solution with the error. it's still buggy, but maybe this will help answer my question better